# Umbraco Sitemap - error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, umbraco8

Umbraco newbie here. I'm following the documentation below to create a sitemap in Umbraco 8.1:

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/tutorials/Creating-an-XML-Site-Map/

Everything seems fine but when I try to put live I get the error: error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'

It seems to not be liking the HTML tags starting at URL - i've tried a few variants on Html.Raw() but it doesn't seem to work. Any help appreciated.

```html
@{
    void RenderSiteMapUrlEntry(IPublishedContent node)
    {
        var changeFreq = node.Value("searchEngineChangeFrequency", fallback: Fallback.To(Fallback.Ancestors, Fallback.DefaultValue), defaultValue: "monthly");
        // with the relative priority, this is a per page setting only, so we're not using recursion, so we won't set Fallback.ToAncestors here and we'll default to 0.5 if no value is set
        var priority = node.HasValue("searchEngineRelativePriority") ? node.Value("searchEngineRelativePriority") : "0.5";

        <url>
            <loc>@node.Url(mode: UrlMode.Absolute)</loc>
            <lastmod>@(string.Format("{0:s}+00:00", node.UpdateDate))</lastmod>
            <changefreq>@changeFreq</changefreq>
            <priority>@priority</priority>
        </url>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I was using the code from Umbraco versions 9 & 10 - i'm using 8 so this worked:

https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Tutorials/Creating-an-XML-Site-Map/index-v8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but from past experience pretty much once in xml mode doesnt like space so when i done this 1 displayed here https://noarlungaunited.com.au/sitemap using pretty much similar code 1st wrapped everything inside  elements and used a helper to get the child elements under home and a function to generate the url, see my full code here.

```html
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@using umbraco.MacroEngines;
@{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    var homeNode = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentType.Alias == "HomePage");
    if (homeNode != null && homeNode.TemplateId > 0)
        {
        var homepage = new DynamicNode(homeNode.Id);
<text><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
            <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemalocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
                <url>
                    <loc>@GetUrlWithDomainPrefix(homeNode.Url)</loc>
                    <lastmod>@(string.Format("{0:s}+00:00", homeNode.UpdateDate))</lastmod>
                    @if (homeNode.GetProperty("sEOSitemapFrequency").HasValue)
                        {
                        <changefreq>@homeNode.GetPropertyValue("sEOSitemapFrequency")</changefreq>
                        }
                    @if (homeNode.GetProperty("sEOSitemapPriority").HasValue)
                        {
                        <priority>@homepage.GetPropertyValue("sEOSitemapPriority")</priority>
                        }
                </url>
                @ListChildNodes(homepage)
            </urlset>
        </text>
        }
}

@helper ListChildNodes(DynamicNode startNode)
    {

        const int maxLevelForSiteMap = 100;


        foreach (DynamicNode node in startNode.ChildrenAsList.Where(x => x.HasAccess && !(x.IsProtected)))
            {
            if (node.template > 0)
                {
                <url>
                    <loc>@GetUrlWithDomainPrefix(node.Url)</loc>
                    <lastmod>@(string.Format("{0:s}+00:00", node.UpdateDate))</lastmod>
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.GetProperty("sEOSitemapFrequency").Value))
                        {
                        <changefreq>@node.GetPropertyValue("sEOSitemapFrequency")</changefreq>
                        }
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.GetProperty("sEOSitemapPriority").Value))
                        {
                        <priority>@node.GetPropertyValue("sEOSitemapPriority")</priority>
                        }
                </url>
                }

            if (node.Level <= maxLevelForSiteMap && node.ChildrenAsList.Count() > 0)
                {
                @ListChildNodes(node)
                }
            }
}

@functions{
    private static string GetUrlWithDomainPrefix(string url)
        {
        if (url.StartsWith("/"))
            url = url.Substring(1);

        var domainPrefix = string.Format("http://{0}/", HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]);

        if (url.StartsWith(domainPrefix))
            return url;
        else
            return domainPrefix + url;
        }
}
```